# XCode automatically commmits any changes to Git

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a project in XCode 5.1.1 and the source is in a Git repository. I use SourceTree for managing the Git repository. Lately I noticed that changes to Images.xcassets would automatically get committed with some old commit message.

At first I thought it might be the Git client so I tried closing the Git client and also tried ither clients but it was still happening. I am now sure that its XCode which is causing this. Has someone faced this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: I would agree to Sulthan, Xcode usually doesn't commit on it's own. Try turning off Xcodes version management.

Comment: Thanks Leandros and Sulthan. I forgot to mention that I am also using git-flow and somewhere along the line I had created a branch manually. This problem seems to have started after that. Maybe I should try disabling git-flow altogether.

Comment: git-flow is great, you should rather try to master it, than to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is your Xcode. Xcode is very simple in handling git. It doesn't do any commits by itself, it doesn't switch your branches (if you don't select the appropiate menu item). It works only on the current branch - when a new file is created, it is added to git, when a file is deleted, it is deleted from git.

Note you can completely turn off Source Control in Xcode Preferences but I guess your problem lies elsewhere.

I saw some people meddling with pre-build/post-build tasks in Xcode to do strange stuff but the most likely cause is a bad state of git branches - bad merging, forcing commits etc. Then the same commit message can appear multiple times but it's just a result of how git tries to synchronize local and remote repositories when forced to.

Comment: I found out what the issue was. Thanks to Sulthan for pointing out pre-build/post-build tasks. I had a script for incrementing versions and tagging releases for archive builds. Turned out my script had a bug which was causing any changes to commit automatically even if its not an archive build. How stupid of me!!